# ¿cómo activar un botón que esta desactivado haciendo click con otro botón? EVENTO AL REFRESCAR PAGINA

Tags: javascript, html

Como hacer que este código cuando le des click y la misma pagina se refresque quede el botón que se QUEDE CON EL MISMO EVENTO ACTIVADO CUANDO SE REFRESQUE LA PÁGINA

```js
    $('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function(){
       //Removemos el atributo 'disabled' del segundo botón, apenas se detecte un click en el primer botón
       $('.jsBtn_2').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="jsBtn_1">Botón 1</button>
    <button class="jsBtn_2" disabled>Botón 2</button>
```

Comment: deberias editar tu pregunta anterior y eliminar esta..!!

Comment: Y de paso explicar mejor lo que quieres porque no se entiende bien. Además, deberías evitar el uso de mayúsculas y revisar la redacción del texto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="jsBtn_1">
        Botón 1
    </button>
    <button class="jsBtn_2" style="display:none">
        Botón 2
    </button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('boton') == 'show'){
        $('.jsBtn_2').show(); 
    }
    $('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function(){
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('boton') == 'show'){
            window.localStorage.setItem('boton', 'hide'); 
            $('.jsBtn_2').hide();           
        }else{
            window.localStorage.setItem('boton', 'show');
            $('.jsBtn_2').show();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: lo de abajo es js

Comment: Me sirvio para darme una idea, y usar sessionStorage gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el `localStorage` para almacenar una variable:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem('boton')) $('.jsBtn_2').removeAttr('disabled');

$('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function(){
  //Removemos el atributo 'disabled' del segundo botón, apenas se detecte un click en el primer botón
  $('.jsBtn_2').removeAttr('disabled');

  window.localStorage.setItem('boton', true);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

La verdad no se entiende muy bien, pero si lo que quieres hacer es que cuando le des click en el boton jsBtn_1 se active el jsBtn_2, lo que tienes que implementar es el hide() o show() de jquery. Ejemplo:

```js
$('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function(){      
       $('.jsBtn_2').show('slow'); 
       /*aca le decis display block como que aparezca y slow es     lentamente*/
       
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="jsBtn_1">Botón 1</button>
<button class="jsBtn_2" style="display:none">Botón 2</button> <!-- Le damos el estilo "display:none" que lo hace invisible. Y luego con jquery lo hacemos aparecer. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.